# Europe: procedure when rental car breaks down far from its base

Tags: europe, car-rentals, emergencies

I'm considering renting a car in France for a longish road trip, including crossing into other countries. I was wondering what is the usual way that things work if the car breaks down (either mechanically, a crash, or a smashed window, etc.) in a city/country other that its base.  I do understand the part about renter's responsibility for damage, and the question is not about that. The question is, if the car is unsuitable to be kept driven, can one get the car exchanged by the rental company? How does that work in practice?

Comment: I would not expect that a single answer would apply to all companies.  You need to ask.  I considered this once, I wanted to rent a car in Portugal and cross into Spain.  The company wanted a significant surcharge.  I forget the amount but I decided to cross the border by bus instead to avoid the cost and hassle.

Comment: Many European rental companies will include additional insurance on the rental that covers repair costs (usually for a separate fee). If you make sure to stick to larger, international companies (like Hertz, Avis, Europcar, etc.) that have locations in the countries you’ll be travelling in, then you should be able to get a replacement from the nearest location. Europcar will sometimes deliver a car to a client in another country from their hub in Stuttgart or Heilbronn if it’s an unusual car type.

Comment: People have tried to edit this into France rather than Europe but this is basically even more world wide than just Europe, so narrowing the area is not useful and will not be accepted.

Comment: @Willeke part of the answer is "ask the rental agency". But part of the answer is also what are the obligation of a rental agency under the local regulations, so that the OP can know what to expect regardless of which agency they end up dealing with. Which is highly specific to the country, and cannot be generalised to Europe (whatever your definition of Europe is)

Comment: @njzk2, as far as I know non of the EU countries have rules for replacement cars in case of broken rentals in the national laws, and in all cases I know of it is between the car rental company and the person renting from them.

Comment: The procedure will depend entirely on the rental company.
Normally it is detailed in the paperwork they hand you with the keys.

Comment: @Willeke If the car is hired out of France, French consumer law would apply so narrowing it down does seem useful and has the added benefit of avoiding a question that's too broad, which we usually frown upon (there is already one close vote).

Answer (score 8):

The usual way to handle is to contact the rental firm and discuss the options.
One is to repair the car, either in a garage or by a roadside breakdown service.
An other is to hand in the car at a local office of the rental company and pick up a replacement car, or have the rental company arrange to have the replacement car brought to you and hand in the keys to the broken one as discussed.

Both options above only work if you are open about your plans and the company agrees for you to take the car out of the country.
International companies with offices in the countries you want to travel are more likely to have an emergency replacement option but small companies might have an insurance covering it or may require you to have an insurance policy for it.

Not being a driver I have traveled in rental cars that did break down, in one case the rental company agreed with the user buying a replacement part and installing it, and on handing in the van they paid for the part and work by reducing the fee to almost nothing. This is an unusual situation, small local company, one of the group a car mechanic, 9 people traveling so replacement transport other than a van would have been hard or expensive.

Which reminds me of one more option, leave the car and return by public transport, which in much of Europe can be a good way if you are near the end of the rental period.

Answer (score 2):

Different rental companies will have different policies and procedures, obviously.

But when it comes to repairs to and possible replacement of a rental car, your first step will always be to contact the rental company. They'll then tell you what is going to happen, whether you should take the car to a local repair shop, whether they're going to send a representative to do that for you, whether you're going to get a replacement car or not and from where (and on what timeframe).

If it's a large company with a presence in the area you're in, most likely that office will handle matters. If they're not, they may have a contract with a company that does have a presence near where you are an defer matters to them.

Worst case, they'll have to send a truck to ferry their car to a repair shop a long way away, and hopefully ferry a replacement car to you. Expensive for them, expensive for you as the risk of that will be reflected in your rental price, and time consuming.